# openlayers-3 mapserver WMS display issue

Tags: openlayers, wms, mapserver, display

I am trying to include a mapserver WMS in Openlayers-3 using custom projection without proj4j.js, according to [this](https://openlayersbook.github.io/ch07-wrapping-our-heads-around-projections/example-03.html). I have no image, no error message and Openlayers is getting mapserver .map according to debug tools, window network. 
[image]
I suppose a problem of projection (?) but can't identify it.

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
     <head>
      <style>
      #map {
        height: 256px;
        width: 512px;
  }
  .ol-attribution a{
    color: black;
  }
      </style>
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.17.1/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<title>OpenLayers 3</title>
</head>
  <body>           
<div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Image({
        title: 'operations Inrap',
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
          url: 'http://10.3.1.51:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:\OSGeo4W\apache\htdocs\fond_mapserver.map',
          params: {'LAYERS': 'Interrégions',
                    //'CRS': 'EPSG:2154',
                    'FORMAT': 'image/jpeg'},
          serverType: 'mapserver',
          extent: [93501.1, 6044342.00, 1248133.25, 7115784.50]
        })
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      projection: new ol.proj.Projection({
      code:'EPSG:2154',
      units: 'm'
        }),       
      center: [681845, 6606361],
      zoom:10
    }),
     controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attributionOptions: {
            collapsible: true
            }
        }), 
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to declare your projection and add it to the ol namespace

```
   var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
    code: 'EPSG:2154',
    extent: [-378305.81,6093283.21, 1212610.74,7186901.68],
    units: 'm'
  });
  ol.proj.addProjection(projection);
```

Then asign this projection to your view

```
.......
view: new ol.View({
      projection: projection,
..........
```

Comment: I just tried this way but get neither error message nor image. I can't see the difference between my code and the one I put in link :'(...

Comment: the only diff is -->`ol.proj.addProjection(projection);` check this example -->http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-custom-proj.html?q=projection

Comment: Yes I saw that in this example and in the lines you wrote. And I have tested it unsuccessfully. In this link : https://openlayersbook.github.io/ch07-wrapping-our-heads-around-projections/example-03.html it seems so "easy", but something is wrong in my code...Thx anw

Comment: The example you refernce is based on a very old version of ol3. Better stick with the latest  ol3 official examples as many changes on the projection's functionality has been made

Comment: I have a doubt : the request sent to mapserver by openlayers begins with :

 10.3.1.51:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:OSGeo4Wapachehtdocs%0Cond_mapserver.map&SERVICE=WMS    &...

I can't see the "/" between C: and OSGeo4W for example, neither the others ??!

Comment: I had to write two "\\" in the mapfile to have the correct request. url: 'http://10.3.1.51:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:\\OSGeo4W\\apache\\htdocs\\fond_mapserver.map'
Thus, I had to remove accent from layer names. Now it works.